# how to declare the interface in Main activity

Tags: java

Example

```
MainActivity{

   interface ProcessData
   {
       void OnProcessData(long[] baLogData);
   }

    ProcessData _processData  ;
   _processData =  (ProcessData)  this; // returns null

}
```

Need to declare the interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need implement **ProcessData** interface for MainActivity. 
For asynchronous tasks prefer to use [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class

```
public class MainActivity implements ProcessData{
    interface ProcessData { void OnProcessData(long[] baLogData); }

    ProcessData _processData;
    YourAsyncTask task;

    public MainActivity(){
        _processData = this;
        task = new YourAsyncTask();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        task.exacute(new YourInputData());
    }

    private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<YourInputData, Integer, long[]> {
        protected Long doInBackground(YourInputData... urls) {
            // proccessing
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // update progress
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(long[]result) {
            // setup result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still i get _processData = null ;

Comment: Can you clarify, why you need `_processData` field?

Comment: 'm using  _processData.OnProcessData(data) to AsyncTaskRunner ,

Comment: In your case, you can pass `MainActivity` directly to `YourAsyncTask` by `this` keyword while async task starting

Comment: yes , 'm using it directly, but as 'm using runnable to processes  the task cant able to access the fragment coz of function , so

Comment: Method `OnProcessData` you wish to use for setup results into fragment?

Comment: thanks, it helped me

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity {

    private long[] data;

    interface ProcessData
    {
        void OnProcessData(long[] baLogData);
    }

    ProcessData _processData = new ProcessData() {
        @Override
        public void OnProcessData(long[] baLogData) {
            //...
        }
    };

    //Usage
    private void someMethod() {
        _processData.OnProcessData(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: no it dint work